# How can I avoid TypeError: MouseSwitch() missing 8 required positional arguments: 'msg', 'x', 'y', 'data', 'time', 'hwnd', and 'window_name'

Tags: python, typeerror, pyhook

Trying to hook into mouse events but in my early tests the program stops responding after about 30 seconds[EDIT: See bottom of post] and gives this error

> TypeError: MouseSwitch() missing 8 required positional arguments: 'msg', 'x', 'y', 'data', 'time', 'hwnd', and 'window_name'

Here's the code. It's supposed to just print all the event info, which it does until it crashes.

```
import pythoncom
import pyHook

def OnMouseEvent(event):
    print ('MessageName:',event.MessageName)
    print ('Message:',event.Message)
    print ('Time:',event.Time)
    print ('Window:',event.Window)
    print ('WindowName:',event.WindowName)
    print ('Position:',event.Position)
    print ('Wheel:',event.Wheel)
    print ('Injected:',event.Injected)
    print ('---')
    return True

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.MouseAll = OnMouseEvent
hm.HookMouse()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE!**
Having done some further testing, the crash only seems to happen when mousing over certain windows (such as the skype contact list). I also get the same error message (but with no crash) if I mouse over the header of a google chrome window.

Comment: Please paste the full traceback, not just the error message at the end.

Comment: It doesn't give one, just gives the one message and stops responding

Comment: what if you remove everything up except `return True` ?

Comment: If I remove everything from `OnMouseEvent` except the `return True` I get the same error.

Comment: Do these libraries use `logging`?  Could we get useful information with a `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` call?

Comment: Doesnt seem to be doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

I had this with `KeyboardSwitch` instead of `MouseSwitch` and traced it to a `UnicodeDecodeError` when pyHook tries to interpret the window name as ascii.  It fails on Skype which has unicode characters in its window name.  I've posted how I fixed it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156633/pythoncom-crashes-on-keydown-when-used-hooked-to-certain-applications).  But I had to rebuild pyHook.

Answer (score 1):

pyHook is more oriented to python 2. There are repositories in github to use it in python 3 as will as modifications and extensions and anymore, better use pynput in python 3 as follows:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pynput.keyboard import Listener

def key_recorder(key):    
    f=open('keylogger.txt','a')
    keyo=str(key)

    if keyo=="Key.enter":
        f.write('\n')
    elif keyo=="Key.space": 
        f.write(" ")
    elif keyo =="Key.backspace":       
        #f.write(keyo.replace(keyo,""))          
        size=f.tell()    # the size... 
        f.truncate(size-1)     
    elif keyo=="Key.alt_l" or keyo=="Key.tab":
        f.write('')  
    elif keyo=="Key.ctrl_l":
        f.write('')    
    elif keyo=="Key.alt_gr":
        f.write('')                                 
    else:
        print(keyo)
        f.write(keyo.replace("'",""))

with Listener(on_press=key_recorder) as l :
    l.join()
```