# pyHook or pythoncom bug?

Tags: python-3.4, skype, pyhook

I have Windows 7, 64 bit. I'm running the example.py file (code posted below) that comes with the pyHook package. Whenever my active window is Skype, either my computer crashes or I get 'TypeError: KeyboardSwitch() missing 8 required positional arguments: ..'. I assume that the code in the example is okay, and if I'm not using Skype it runs fine. Any thoughts?

```
from __future__ import print_function

import pyHook

def OnMouseEvent(event):
    print('MessageName:',event.MessageName)
    print('Message:',event.Message)
    print('Time:',event.Time)
    print('Window:',event.Window)
    print('WindowName:',event.WindowName)
    print('Position:',event.Position)
    print('Wheel:',event.Wheel)
    print('Injected:',event.Injected)
    print('---')

    # return True to pass the event to other handlers
    # return False to stop the event from propagating
    return True

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    print('MessageName:',event.MessageName)
    print('Message:',event.Message)
    print('Time:',event.Time)
    print('Window:',event.Window)
    print('WindowName:',event.WindowName)
    print('Ascii:', event.Ascii, chr(event.Ascii))
    print('Key:', event.Key)
    print('KeyID:', event.KeyID)
    print('ScanCode:', event.ScanCode)
    print('Extended:', event.Extended)
    print('Injected:', event.Injected)
    print('Alt', event.Alt)
    print('Transition', event.Transition)
    print('---')

    # return True to pass the event to other handlers
    # return False to stop the event from propagating
    return True

# create the hook mananger
hm = pyHook.HookManager()
# register two callbacks
hm.MouseAllButtonsDown = OnMouseEvent
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent

# hook into the mouse and keyboard events
hm.HookMouse()
hm.HookKeyboard()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pythoncom
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this and traced it to a `UnicodeDecodeError` when pyHook tries to interpret the window name as ascii.  It fails on Skype which has unicode characters in its window name.  I've posted how I fixed it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156633/pythoncom-crashes-on-keydown-when-used-hooked-to-certain-applications).  But I had to rebuild pyHook.

PS: kind of a duplicate answer but wanted to connect this question to what I found.