# How to rebuild a Python module/library

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, pyhook

I'm trying to rebuild the pyhook libary as described in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33357202/5864903).

Basically, I need to change a few lines of the C code for the pyhook module.

The problem is I don't know how to access the C code or how to rebuild the libary.

I've heard of Cython but I don't understand it and I don't know how to use it.

Also, I would like the solution to be compatible with py2exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the C code first - it's not part of the exe install. Unzip it and you then have a source tree that will build.

To build it you'll need a C compiler.  You need to use the SAME ONE as your Python version for your platform.  For example, for Windows and Python 3.5 you need the latest Visual C from Microsoft.

For pyHook you also need SWIG.  Use that to construct cpyHook_wrap.c from the supplied cpyHook.i

Then run setup.py and you should be good to go.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without a ressource consuming program (Visual C)? Do C compilers exist on their own and would they work?

Comment: You need to use the same compiler as the version of python you are using.  The visual C compiler is not big but I don't know how to install it on its own.