# Listen for a shortcut (like WIN+A) even if the Python script does not have the focus

Tags: python, windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like a Python script to run constantly in background and do something when a certain keyboard shortcut is pressed, such as <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

I've read [Key Listeners in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918999/key-listeners-in-python) and solutions using `pynput`, but it seems to work and detect key presses when the window/console has focus.

**Question: how to detect a keyboard shortcut in Python, such as <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and launch a function when it happens, even if the focus is somewhere else (e.g. browser, etc.)?**

Note: my OS is Windows. Also I would prefer that the Python script only "registers" listening to <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (does this exist?), and does not listen to all keypresses (otherwise it would be more or less a keylogger, which I don't want!).

---

Here is what I have tried:

```
import pyHook, pythoncom

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    if event.Ascii == 8:  # backspace 
        print('hello')
    return True
    
hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

I would like to avoid it for 2 reasons: first, I find it very intrusive to listen to all keypresses and secondly, this common example about `pyhook` I found in many places has a bug: [`TypeError: KeyboardSwitch() missing 8 required positional arguments: 'msg', 'vk_ code', 'scan_code', 'ascii', 'flags', 'time', 'hwnd', and 'win_name'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156633/pythoncom-crashes-on-keydown-when-used-hooked-to-certain-applications). The new version PyHook3 doesn't seem to work for Py36-64 either: `pip install PyHook3` fails on Windows.

Comment: You're looking for the Windows API "RegisterHotKey". Here is an example using it with Python: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/catch_system_wide_hotkeys.html

Comment: I think you can post this as an answer @fpbhb! (Maybe with sample code).

Comment: You did it better than me ;-) +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, I was wrong: `pynput` is indeed able to detect key presses globally, and not only for the currently active window.

## 1) Using `pynput`

This following code launches the application `notepad` with <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and `calc` with <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

```
from pynput import keyboard
import subprocess

pressed = set()

COMBINATIONS = [
    {
        "keys": [
            {keyboard.Key.cmd, keyboard.KeyCode(char="w")},
            {keyboard.Key.cmd, keyboard.KeyCode(char="W")},
        ],
        "command": "notepad",
    },
    {
        "keys": [
            {keyboard.Key.cmd, keyboard.KeyCode(char="c")},
            {keyboard.Key.cmd, keyboard.KeyCode(char="C")},
        ],
        "command": "calc",
    },
]

def run(s):
    subprocess.Popen(s)

def on_press(key):
    pressed.add(key)
    print(pressed)
    for c in COMBINATIONS:
        for keys in c["keys"]:
            if keys.issubset(pressed):
                run(c["command"])

def on_release(key):
    if key in pressed:
        pressed.remove(key)

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

---

## 2) Using `ctypes` and `win32con`

This is inspired by [this post](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/catch_system_wide_hotkeys.html) cited by @fpbhb in a comment. It listens to <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

```
import os, sys
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes
import win32con

def handle_win_f3():
    os.startfile(os.environ["TEMP"])

def handle_win_f4():
    ctypes.windll.user32.PostQuitMessage(0)

HOTKEYS = [
    {"keys": (win32con.VK_F3, win32con.MOD_WIN), "command": handle_win_f3},
    {"keys": (win32con.VK_F4, win32con.MOD_WIN), "command": handle_win_f4},
]

for i, h in enumerate(HOTKEYS):
    vk, modifiers = h["keys"]
    print("Registering id", i, "for key", vk)
    if not ctypes.windll.user32.RegisterHotKey(None, i, modifiers, vk):
        print("Unable to register id", i)
try:
    msg = wintypes.MSG()
    while ctypes.windll.user32.GetMessageA(ctypes.byref(msg), None, 0, 0) != 0:
        if msg.message == win32con.WM_HOTKEY:
            HOTKEYS[msg.wParam]["command"]()
        ctypes.windll.user32.TranslateMessage(ctypes.byref(msg))
        ctypes.windll.user32.DispatchMessageA(ctypes.byref(msg))
finally:
    for i, h in enumerate(HOTKEYS):
        ctypes.windll.user32.UnregisterHotKey(None, i)
```

---

## 3) Using `keyboard`

See https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard. It is interesting, but for me it had some drawbacks compared to other solutions: some fast keystrokes (while CPU-intensive processing is done) were not caught. They were caught when using solution 1) or 2).

---

It seems there is no 100% Tkinter solution, see [Capture all keypresses of the system with Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71524462/capture-all-keypresses-of-the-system-with-tkinter).